# Calculating time difference with values retrieved from MySQL TIME field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've done a bit of searching and there is a bunch of information on calculating time difference between two times using `strtotime('09:00:00)` and then putting this against another value.

Currently, I have a database that stores regular hours for staff like so:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| staff_id |    day    | start_time | finish_time | total_breaks |
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
|        1 | Monday    | 18:00:00   | 22:00:00    |            0 |
|        2 | Wednesday | 09:00:00   | 17:30:00    |           30 |
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

`start_time` and `finish_time` are stored as `TIME` values in MySQL and `total_breaks` as an `INT` which I should probably convert to `TIME` values as well and represent as `00:30:00` or `00:00:00` for consistency.

What I want to be able to do is display a table that displays all of this information, as well as their total hours worked and then total hours minus any breaks.

I've been able to generate a table with the `staff_id`, `day`, `start_time` and `finish_time` but am struggling to figure out the best way to calculate the total amount of time worked etc.

I'm using Laravel, and have read that `strtotime('00:00:00')` is a great way to do this but this won't work as I'm not using a string but rather pulling the time from the database.

What is the best way to calculate the time difference between the two times, and then take in to account the breaks as well.

Have I even set this up correctly? I don't want to set the times up as a DATETIME as I'm just wanting to calculate the time difference of their normal working hours which they do from week to week - although I can always use dummy dates to get this working if necessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know how long each break was?

Comment: Based on the hours that they work, I know how much time they are allocated for breaks. I don't need to know the exact amount of time they took, just what they should've taken based on their start and finish times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make things overly complicated.

You can always convert your database times to epoch time using `strtotime`

```
<?php
$start_time = '2015-09-23 22:00:00'; // pulled from DB
$finish_time = '2015-09-24 06:00:00'; // pulled from DB
$starttime = strtotime($start_time); // convert to timestring
$endtime = strtotime($finish_time); // convert to timestring
$diff = $endtime - $starttime; // do the math

$total_breaks = 30; // pulled from DB
$breaks = $total_breaks*60; // minutes * seconds per minute
$hours = ($diff - $breaks)/60/60; // do the math converting seconds to hours
?>
```

The above code will output like this...

```
<?php
echo 'clocked in: '.$start_time.'<br>';
echo 'clocked out: '.$finish_time.'<br>';
echo 'breaks: '.$total_breaks.' minutes<br>';
echo 'hours worked: '.number_format($hours, 2).'<br>';
?>
```

> clocked in: 2015-09-23 22:00:00
> clocked out: 2015-09-24 06:00:00
> breaks: 30 minutes
> hours worked: 7.50

**Suggestion:** Change your `start_time` and `finish_time` fields to `DATETIME` so you won't have a problem if someone works through midnight to the next day like in the code I used.

**NOTE:** If you use `strtotime` without a date specified like `strtotime(09:00:00)` ... the current date will be automatically added to form a complete `DateTime`. **BUT** if anyone works through midnight the calculation will yield a negative number.

**IF** no one works through midnight you can just use the `Time` as your data like so...

```
<?php
$start_time = '09:00:00';
$finish_time = '17:00:00';
$starttime = strtotime($start_time);
$endtime = strtotime($finish_time);
etc...
?>
```

Comment: the reason I don't have them as `DATETIME` is because this is just their regular hours and isn't a clock in/clock out thing. I'm wanting to store their regular hours so that I can use it later on down the track so having a date in with that isn't necessary as it will never be used. However, if putting a standalone date that is just used from then on out (e.g using `'2015-09-23 22:00:00';` for the life of the application) in there makes it easier to use then I can do that.
Does that change things from your end at all?

Comment: Only slightly... you would simply concatenate the two fields together to form a complete `DateTime` to get your `strtotime` from. I understand what you're saying. I don't know if there are any employees who work overnight, but if there are the date as well as the time would be required for an accurate calculation.

Comment: @James - See my updated answer (notes) in response to your time field.

Comment: How i could able to counter the early timein timeout if ever?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a few things in your question, so I'll start with a query to begin and we can increase whats in here as we move on.

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF( '09:00:00', '17:30:00' );
+------------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF( '09:00:00', '17:30:00' ) |
+------------------------------------+
| -08:30:00                          |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You could include that to work out the total time from start to finish ... `TIMEDIFF( start_time, finish_time ) AS total_time`.

Then, we need to deduct the total minutes from that value.

Once we know how many minutes have been taken as breaks ...

```
mysql> select ADDTIME('08:00:00', '00:30:00');
+---------------------------------+
| ADDTIME('08:00:00', '00:30:00') |
+---------------------------------+
| 08:30:00                        |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How does that look?

Ok, so doing a similar calculation in PHP is easy.

```
$start_time = new DateTime($your_start_time);
$finish_time = new DateTime($your_finish_time);
$diff = $start_time->Diff($finish_time);
$hours = $diff->format("%H");
```

Also, when you have finish_time. You can remove time from it (based on breaks) like so (30 is 30 mins);

```
$finish_time->sub(new DateInterval('PT30M'));
```

Comment: OK, so inside my controller I pull the hours for a particular staff member. I then return the results to my view to be displayed. Using `TIMEDIFF`, could I call it like so `$totalhours = TIMEDIFF($staff->start_time, $staff->finish_time);`

Comment: @James I am doing these calculations in MySQL... I'll need to convert them to PHP.

Comment: Ideally, what I'm after is a way to calculate the difference inside Laravel after I have retrieved the values. So I retrieve them using an Eloquent query (`$staff = Staff::find($id);`) and then I want to use the results to calculate the time difference. This way I simply need to load any new hours in to the database and the calculation in the controller will stay the same for each result set.

Comment: OK thanks, I will give this a go shortly. I would need to use it like `$start_time = new DateTime($staff->start_time);` rather than setting it as a string but that should still work fine right?

Comment: Yeah absolutely it will. See latest update with removing break time from finish time.

Comment: Have added variables in so you can see.